# getting wrong values looping through array for a particular value in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a function that is supposed to loop through an array and count the values in the array that are true. in the example below, I am expecting a value of 4, since the values 6, 3, 30, and 7 are all truthy values while 0 is false.

```
function countTruthy(arr) {
    var arrayLength = arr.length;
    var truthy = 0;

    for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
    if(arr[i] == true) {
        truthy++
    }
  }
  
  return console.log(truthy)
}

countTruthy([6, 3, 0, 30, 7])
```

But the code above doesn't work and I keep getting 0 instead

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While all non-zero numbers are truthy, it is not equal to `true`. Only `1` is equal to `true`. To double-check this, just try running `60 == true` in your console and it will return `false`, however, if you run `if (60) console.log('hi')` it will print `'hi'`.

tl;dr: Truthy values are not necessarily equal to `true`.

To fix this, just check if the value is 0 instead. Like this:

```js
function countTruthy(arr) {
  return arr.filter(x => x != 0).length;
}

console.log(countTruthy([6, 3, 0, 30, 7]))
```

Also, your function can be drastically reduced with [`.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Filter). Just filter out all the zero values then return the length of the resulting array.

Answer (score 3):

Whether a value is "truthy" (like 6 is truthy, but not really equal to `true`) has a meaning that goes beyond just numbers, and besides 0, also `NaN` is a falsy value in the numeric data type domain. To accurately count truthy values, you can use `Boolean` as call back, like this:

```js
const countTruthy = arr => arr.filter(Boolean).length;

console.log(countTruthy([6, 3, 0, 30, 7]));  // 4
console.log(countTruthy([6, 3, NaN, 30, 7]));  // 4
console.log(countTruthy(["a", "b", "", "c", "d"]));  // 4
console.log(countTruthy([true, true, false, true, true]));  // 4
console.log(countTruthy([{}, undefined, null]));  // 1
```

Answer (score 2):

As @Michael mentioned above, 0 is `false` but not all truthy values are equal to true. With that said, here is how you can achieve the desired result.

```js
function countTruthy(arr) {
  var arrayLength = arr.length;
  var truthy = 0;

  for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
    if (arr[i]) {
      truthy += 1;
    }
  }

  return console.log(truthy);
}

countTruthy([6, 3, 0, 30, 7])
```